# Does anyone have the datasheet for this display?

Tags: led-matrix

Does anyone have the datasheet for this display there is no serial number or Ebay link. A student came to me with this 4 digit 7 segment LED, there are 12 pins in one side, and nothing on the other side. Model number is, WP02841MGA.

[image: 7]

Comment: Send the aforementioned student to search for the datasheet.  He might learn that a component without a datasheet is junk.

Comment: The part number is right there. It's probably a custom ordered part, just look for similar part numbers.

Comment: Just search for similar part with same pin configuration. Many are pin compatible. Use a multimeter with a diode test to make sure. In case of internal series resistors, use a ohmmeter and a laboratory power supply and light the LEDs up.

Comment: Nick Alexeev it's a cute kid right :D !
Passerby " It's probably a custom ordered part" exactly you can't found anything with that number. FRob i search allot, all what i found is 6 legs in each side, there is no 12 legs in one side
Spehro Pefhany that's exactly what i will do :) Passerby ok thanks for you too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after testing, this is the result :) thanks everyone - if someone have problem just use this
always the (-) is the first number

[image: led]

Comment: Somewhat similar [block of 7-segment digits](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LTC-4727JR/160-1551-5-ND/408224) ([datasheet](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS30-2000-193/S_110_C4727JR.pdf)).

Comment: Seems odd (but not impossible) that the digits would be wired that way (reverse)- are you sure it's not the (left-right) reverse of that?

Comment: ops i forget to say that, it's upside down, just rotate it :)
thanks @Nick Alexeev :D late but helpful too

Answer (score 11):

If you just want the pinout, poke around with a 5V supply with a 1k resistor in series and in minutes you'll have it.

With 12 pins it's a multiplexed display with at least four commons. Could be common anode or common cathode, some of the positions (colon, some or all decimal points) may not be populated.

Comment: Exactly, just assume 20mA or less per diode and your golden.

Comment: @Passerby *You're. I'm not a grammar Nazi or something, but it changes the meaning of the comment.